# Javascript Regular Expression For a Valid Input

Tags: javascript

I want JavaScript regular expression which validates below number format (only number and min length should be 11 and maximum 16).
e.g

```
12345678901 // valid  
+1234567890 // valid  
+1234567890+ // invalid  
+123456789trtr // invalid  
+trtr // invalid
```

Comment: Minimal length should be 11? Your first example has 10 digits.

Comment: By min length, do you mean there should be at least 11 characters in the string?

Comment: @WillReese Yes. string which contains only numbers

Comment: @EganWolf. I have update question. sorry for inconvinience

Comment: You say "only number", yet you give examples which have a `+` at the beginning. What is the complete, correct rule for validity?

Comment: Use basic regexp syntax for optional characters (`?`) and digits (`\d`) and repetition count (`{min,max}`).

Comment: a Phone number, is it??

Comment: @JinsPeter Yes it is for a phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works assuming that only digits are allowed, and + is allowed at the beginning of the string.

```
/^(?:\+\d{10,15}|\d{11,16})$/
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex:

```
/([+]?[0-9]{1,10})\w+/g
```

Comment: hello Arvind , It's not working for input like '+3435435435u'.

Comment: did you test the regex before answering my question

Comment: Sorry, I missed to test last 2 option, now tested with regex as following ([+]?\d{10,16})

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple RegExp for what you want to get will be:

```
/^\+?\d{11,16}$/
```

It returns you a string with a possible `+` sign at the beginning followed by 11 - 16 digits.

As user [Jins Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6128864/jins-peter) suggested, you probably want a RegExp that validates phone number.

If it is really a phone number there often will be spaces in it. Also area code would be optional. So in the end I suggest using:

```
/^(\+?\d{2})? ?\d{3} ?\d{3} ?\d{3}$/
```

It makes the examples below pass the RegExp:

```
+48 666 555 444 //valid
48 666 555 444 //valid
+48666555444 //valid
48666555444 //valid
666555444 //valid
666 555 444 //valid
```

Keep in mind that some weird phone numbers will also pass the validation. For example:

```
48 666 555444 //valid
+48666555 444 //valid
```

etc.